# Change height of UIView inside of UITableViewCell (Storyboards)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I'm trying to create a master UITableViewCell with storyboards. The idea is that this cell contains all the possible subviews, but not all will be shown depending on the data for each cell.

I calculate the appropriate height for each cell depending on the data using the **heightForRowAtIndexPath** and this is working fine.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to adjust the height of subviews to zero inside the tableViewCell to effectively hide those elements while still respecting the relative constraints I set up (unlike removing the subviews from the superview which messes up all my constraints).

So basically I can't seem to figure out how to update the height(frame) of a subview (UIView) inside a UITableViewCell using storyboards and autolayout.

Any guidance would be awesome, and please let me know if I'm not using the best paradigm or thought process for the desired effect.

Best,

emjoseph

Comment: did you try with constants? since you are using autolayout, you should use them instead of changing width & height.

Comment: If you don't need to resize the cell when the UIView height should be zero, can you just use the hidden property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use `NSLayoutConstraint`'s. If your cell subviews do not already have fixed heights, you'll need to add them.

Once you've added those constraints, create references to your header file for those constraints. To do this, double click the height constraint so that it reveals itself in your `ViewController` structure, then control click and drag into your header file.

When you've decided which view to collapse, access your newly declared `NSLayoutConstraint` and edit the constant value.

*Example:*

```
subviewHeight.constant = 0;
```